# Geany doesn't support x-selection paste inside same file?

Tags: interface, geany

On the Ubuntu environment, I find it very handy that I can select some text somewhere, and then middle-click somewhere else and the text will be pasted.

Geany supports pasting text this way, as long as it was selected somewhere else.

However, if I select some text *inside* a file in geany, and then middle click somewhere else *in the same file*, it won't paste anything. However if I middle click on another file in Geany, it will paste the selected text.

Is there a reason for this behavior? Why I cannot select + middle-click-paste in the same file in Geany?

Comment: This is working -- just tried it. Which version of geany are you using?